# error import csv to mysql php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, csv

I have problem to import csv file to mysql and I'm not familiar in this topic,here is the code that I want to use to import csv file to mysql ,I dont have a idea why it still give a error .I need someone to help me check what is wrong in my coding here.

**import.php**

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() { 

                $('#submit').live('click', function(){ 
                  $("#imageform").submit();

                });
            }); 




            </script>

    </head>
     <body>
     <div id="imp1">
     <div id="import">Importing into Current Server</div>
     <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="validate.php">
     <div class="far">
        <label id="sel">Upload File</label>
            <div class="far1">
            <div id="preview"></div>
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#"><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><span></span></a></div></form>
    </div>  
   </body>
```

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "sample";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

**validate.php**

```
     include "mysql.php"; //Connect to Database

        $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE customer";
        mysql_query($deleterecords);

        //Upload File
        if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
             $fname = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

             $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

             if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
             {

                 $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                 $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

                 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                 {
                    $sql = "INSERT into customer(item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11) 
    values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";
//item1 is AI
                    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                 } 

                 fclose($handle);
                 echo "Successfully Imported";
             }
             else
             {
                 echo "Invalid File";
             }    
        }


        ?>
```

Thanks for your help .

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: Server error.The website encountered an error while retrieving localhost/import/import/validate.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.  << When I check the table the value in item1 that I set as auto increment is increasing.I'm get so confused now

Comment: that is a very generic error - e.g. it can be caused by duplicate function names, mismatched quotes, lack of `;` etc - look in your log files and see what the actual error was.

Comment: @ZackNewsham I already found the problem ,got same ['name'] in $fname = $_FILES['filename']['name']; -at line 9 with $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name']; -at line 16 . please forward back your previous comment so I can mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be caused by duplicate function names, mismatched quotes, lack of ; etc.

In this case the problem was solved by replacing $fname = $_FILES['filename']['name']; -at line 9 with $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name']; at line 16